# How to convert nested list (3D) to an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a nested lists in list that I want convert to numpy array. Any ideas how to make it work? How to "obey" these dimensions or something? These are the shapes of particular dimensions (5249, 40, 94) and here is some code to take a look at:

```
print(list[0])
print("")
print("############################################################################################################")
print("")
print(list[0][0])
print("")
print("############################################################################################################")
print("")
print(list[0][0][0])
```

Output:

```
[[-6.61763245e+02 -6.64446411e+02 -6.69300354e+02 ... -5.77811462e+02
  -6.03125916e+02 -6.44908325e+02]
 [ 5.16810684e+01  4.93927383e+01  4.33423386e+01 ...  1.15522194e+02
   1.02576866e+02  7.31012421e+01]
 [ 2.85251961e+01  2.91995888e+01  2.44578667e+01 ...  2.78144531e+01
   3.44897461e+01  4.35078812e+01]
 ...
 [-4.82816219e-01  2.96157646e+00  4.19265079e+00 ... -5.56250429e+00
  -2.69588089e+00  9.44380760e-02]
 [ 2.64353752e-01  4.48119164e+00  6.22685146e+00 ... -5.64488232e-01
  -9.20243263e-02  2.12504435e+00]
 [ 3.63748550e-01  4.75209856e+00  7.24038124e+00 ...  7.15274096e+00
   7.77531719e+00  5.09825420e+00]]

############################################################################################################

[-661.76324 -664.4464  -669.30035 -679.77814 -690.35443 -660.9415
 -559.9239  -485.485   -438.78836 -415.3624  -390.37952 -373.00934
 -362.99307 -373.43564 -398.9366  -370.4043  -316.54483 -302.01596
 -297.92493 -276.72098 -247.64464 -265.17184 -323.19016 -389.68723
 -405.23648 -405.97824 -401.15686 -393.97366 -389.72104 -393.87613
 -421.2706  -453.30283 -476.209   -510.27377 -484.22525 -449.0411
 -436.07883 -417.73248 -406.98907 -427.94107 -463.365   -505.69937
 -551.2041  -583.83923 -593.5474  -574.877   -544.497   -496.86914
 -455.1289  -441.72507 -426.9304  -424.22696 -431.49948 -427.11542
 -426.9054  -421.04877 -410.71277 -420.71997 -432.1894  -438.21225
 -488.68088 -560.41223 -603.5054  -563.4358  -519.3162  -518.875
 -546.30237 -547.3298  -549.09814 -543.82275 -512.5244  -439.3493
 -380.52084 -343.0858  -314.34274 -307.8192  -345.0038  -380.26834
 -358.30072 -338.74014 -324.08173 -323.67844 -338.8997  -376.0949
 -407.73825 -472.8915  -571.7233  -632.6836  -669.91046 -646.43445
 -607.1672  -577.81146 -603.1259  -644.9083 ]

############################################################################################################

-661.76324
```

When I try convert it to the array, I get this error:

```
>>> list_x = np.asarray(list)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (40,94) into shape (40) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-eaaeafee7c41> in <module>
----> 1 list_x = np.asarray(list)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (40,94) into shape (40)
```

Comment: The sublists are not consistent in shape.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure will work if all sublists have the same length. As noted in the comments, most likely the length of 1 or more sublists is inconsistent.

See code below to confirm this works as expected. The first 4 lines create the starting list (`l1`) from a np.array (`start`). The last 3 lines create the array from the list, then print the new array shape and contents.

```
a0, a1, a2 = 4, 3, 2
start = np.arange(a0*a1*a2).reshape(a0,a1,a2)
print(start)   
l1 = start.tolist()

end = np.array(l1)
print('\n end shape=',end.shape,'\n')
print(end)
```

Here is a way to test your list of lists before you attempt to create the array. The code below continues from the example above. It adds an item to 2 sublists, then loops to count and saves the counts in array `arr_cnt`. The last step tests if all values in `arr_cnt` are identical (or not). It will print `False` for this example.

```
l1[0][0].append(3)
l1[-1][-1].append(5)
print(l1)

arr_cnt=np.empty( (len(l1),len(l1[0])), dtype=int)
for i,l2 in enumerate(l1):
    for j,l3 in enumerate(l2):
        arr_cnt[i,j] = len(l3)
        
# test arr_cnt values; True when all values are identical
print( (arr_cnt[0] == arr_cnt).all() )
```